# Find Dupes in one column base on values in another

Tags: vba, excel

I'm hoping somebody can help me out with this. I attached a screen shot. The far 2 right columns are zip codes. The far right columns are duplicate zip codes found in the column just to the left.  But it's grabbing all the zip dupes.

The other thing I need dupes from specific date. So only for 6/7  and only for 6/9.  My code is below.  Not sure what I'm missing.

```
   Sub ListDuplicatedZipsInColumnI()

   Dim strCurrentRowZips As String
   Dim strCurrentRowZipArray() As String

   Dim foundZips As String

   Dim zipCell As String
   Dim foundCell As String
   Dim allZipCell As String



   Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    'Ctrl + Shift + End
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    'Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  Dim firstDataRowNum As Integer
  firstDataRowNum = 2

   For RowNum = firstDataRowNum To LastRow
   zipCell = "H" & RowNum
   foundCell = "I" & RowNum

   Dim strAllExceptCurrentRowZips As String
   Dim strAllExceptCurrentRowZipArray() As String
   'NEW CODE START****
    Dim RowNum_C As Long, LastRow_C As Long
'turn off screen updating
''Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'start below titles and make full selection of data
RowNum_C = 2
LastRow_C = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Range("A2", Cells(LastRow_C, 4)).Select
    'NEW CODE END****

   strAllExceptCurrentRowZips = ""


          'NEW CODE START****
               For Each Row In Selection
    With Cells

    If Cells(RowNum_C, 2) = Cells(RowNum_C + 1, 2) Then


           ' move attribute 2 up next to attribute 1 and delete empty line
            Cells(RowNum_C + 1, 9).Copy Destination:=Cells(RowNum_C, 10)
            Rows(RowNum_C + 1).EntireRow.Delete
     '   End If
     End If
  '  End With
'increase RowNum_C for next test
RowNum_C = RowNum_C + 1
Next Row

                 'NEW CODE END ****
'            If allRowNum <> RowNum Then
'                 allZipCell = "H" & allRowNum
'
'                 If (LTrim(RTrim(Range(allZipCell).Value)) <> "") Then
'                    strAllExceptCurrentRowZips = Replace(strAllExceptCurrentRowZips, " ", "") & "," & Replace(Range(allZipCell).Value, " ", "")
'
'                 End If
'            End If
'         End If
'    Next


   foundZips = ""

   strArray = Split(Replace(Range(zipCell).Value, " ", ""), ",")

   For intCount = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
      Debug.Print Trim(strArray(intCount))
      If InStr(strAllExceptCurrentRowZips, strArray(intCount)) > 0 Then
        If Len(foundZips) > 0 Then
            foundZips = foundZips & ", "
        End If
        foundZips = foundZips & strArray(intCount)
      End If

   Next

   Range(foundCell).Value = "'" & foundZips

   Next


End Sub
```

[image: Screen shot of current results]

Comment: You said "it's grabbing all the zip dupes" but is that not what you want?

Comment: Hi Matt.  I need to grab only dupes for the 7th or only for the 9th. Currently it's grabbing for both days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just check for those days before you do your de-duping. Like so

```
if Range("A" & RowNum) = "6/7/2016" or Range("A" & RowNum) = "6/9/2016" then    
    strArray = Split(Replace(Range(zipCell).Value, " ", ""), ",")

    For intCount = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
        Debug.Print Trim(strArray(intCount))
        If InStr(strAllExceptCurrentRowZips, strArray(intCount)) > 0 Then
            If Len(foundZips) > 0 Then
                foundZips = foundZips & ", "
            End If
            foundZips = foundZips & strArray(intCount)
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I'll try that out.  So I need to match it to any date that is in the column.  Do you think the best way is just to read the value, and then loop through?